# Opposite of Ground Up

Tags: expressions, antonyms

Is there any opposite of "Ground up" phrase? Something like "Top-down : Bottom-up"

Comment: The literal opposite would be _sky down_, but that's not an idiom as far as I know. _Top down_ would be the likeliest candidate

Comment: What's the context?

Comment: @batpigandme "I built it from the ground up"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Top down" would be the opposite. For example, you could build something *from the ground up* or *from the top down.* Conversely, *from the bottom up* would have the same meaning as *from the ground up.*

Answer (score 2):

The phrase *from the ground up* generally means *completely* or starting from scratch, as in [this definition](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/from+the+ground+up).

While *top down* seems like a linguistic opposite, the meaning is not quite right. It may refer to an [analytic method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_and_bottom-up_design) or an organizational or decision making [structure](http://www.designsontalent.com/blog/bid/85954/Top-Down-and-Bottom-Up-Organization-Design).

When a task is not approached *from the ground up*, it is being done *incrementally*, or perhaps *superficially*.  If you wish to convey that the actor is not paying attention to basics or fundamentals, you could say *his head is in the clouds* or *he is living in an ivory tower*.

Answer (score 0):

I agree partly with bib that we're looking for an opposite to *starting from scratch* rather than a literally physically opposite metaphor.

Another way to consider this opposite is to think of someone participating after completion, so maybe *after the fact* would work?

Or, if you're taking the **not** from the start approach, think incremental change of something substantial, such as *standing on the shoulders of ...* or *organic improvement*?